# NHibernate pass Geography type to Named Query SetParameter()

Tags: nhibernate, named-query, sqlgeography

I'm in the process of introducing NHibernate 3 into a data access layer for an ASP.NET MVC web application.

Within the SQL Server 2008 R2 database, a `geography` datatype is used to store lat/long coordinates in a table that maps to an entity within the application (call this `EntityA`).

I've set up fluent mappings to succesfully map the datatype to a property on `EntityA` of type `GisSharpBlog.NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point`, with a custom mapping convention that maps it to a derived `MsSql2008GeographyType`.

The above all appears to be working correctly, but there are some stored procedures that are still used that expect one parameter to be of type `geography`. I've mapped the stored procedures as named queries, but I can't seem to figure out what type I should pass for the parameter of type `geography`. The method in which the query call happens takes a `double` latitude and a `double` longitude. In the old sproc call the mapping was done with

```
private static SqlGeography GetPoint(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    var geographyBuilder = new SqlGeographyBuilder();
    geographyBuilder.SetSrid(4326);
    geographyBuilder.BeginGeography(OpenGisGeographyType.Point);
    geographyBuilder.BeginFigure(latitude, longitude);
    geographyBuilder.EndFigure();
    geographyBuilder.EndGeography();
    return geographyBuilder.ConstructedGeography;
}

var point = GetPoint(latitude, longitude);

command.Parameters.Add(
    new SqlParameter("@Location", point) { UdtTypeName = "Geography" });
```

Running the SQL Profiler, the following command is executed

```
declare @p3 sys.geography
set @p3=convert(sys.geography,0xE6100000010CAD4D637B2DBA49400BEE77280AB404C0)
exec my-sproc-name @Location=@p3
```

When I try mapping with the following

```
var query = Session.GetNamedQuery("my-sproc-name");

var point = 
    new GisSharpBlog.NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point(longitude, latitude);
query.SetParameter("Location", point);
```

I get a SqlException with `Error converting data type varbinary to geography`

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Error converting data type varbinary to
>   geography. Error converting data type varbinary to geography.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection) +2073502
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5064460
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +2275
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +33
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +86
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +311
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async) +987
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) +32
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +141
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +12
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>   +12    NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd) +356    NHibernate.Driver.BatcherDataReaderWrapper..ctor(IBatcher batcher, IDbCommand command) +183
>   NHibernate.Driver.BasicResultSetsCommand.GetReader(Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout) +432    NHibernate.Impl.MultiQueryImpl.DoList() +683

Running the SQL Profiler, the following command is executed

```
exec sp_executesql N'exec my-sproc-name @p0' @p0=0x0001000000FFFFFFFF01000000000000000C02000000574E6574546F706F6C6F677953756974652C2056657273696F6E3D312E372E332E31373239382C2043756C747572653D6E65757472616C2C205075626C69634B6579546F6B656E3D663538306130353031366562616461310C030000004947656F4150492C2056657273696F6E3D312E312E302E302C2043756C747572653D6E65757472616C2C205075626C69634B6579546F6B656E3D6131613064613764656634363536373805010000002E4769735368617270426C6F672E4E6574546F706F6C6F677953756974652E47656F6D6574726965732E506F696E74090000000B636F6F7264696E6174657308656E76656C6F70651047656F6D657472792B666163746F72791147656F6D657472792B75736572446174611147656F6D657472792B656E76656C6F70650D47656F6D657472792B737269641247656F6D657472792B64696D656E73696F6E1147656F6D657472792B626F756E646172791A47656F6D657472792B626F756E6461727944696D656E73696F6E040404020400040404404769735368617270426C6F672E4E6574546F706F6C6F677953756974652E47656F6D6574726965732E436F6F7264696E617465417272617953657175656E6365020000001B47656F4150492E47656F6D6574726965732E49456E76656C6F706503000000384769735368617270426C6F672E4E6574546F706F6C6F677953756974652E47656F6D6574726965732E47656F6D65747279466163746F7279020000001B47656F4150492E47656F6D6574726965732E49456E76656C6F706503000000081C47656F4150492E47656F6D6574726965732E44696D656E73696F6E73030000001B47656F4150492E47656F6D6574726965732E4947656F6D65747279030000001C47656F4150492E47656F6D6574726965732E44696D656E73696F6E73030000000200000009040000000A09050000000A0A0000000005FAFFFFFF1C47656F4150492E47656F6D6574726965732E44696D656E73696F6E73010000000776616C75655F5F000803000000000000000A01F9FFFFFFFAFFFFFF000000000504000000404769735368617270426C6F672E4E6574546F706F6C6F677953756974652E47656F6D6574726965732E436F6F7264696E617465417272617953657175656E6365010000000B636F6F7264696E61746573041F47656F4150492E47656F6D6574726965732E49436F6F7264696E6174655B5D030000000200000009080000000505000000384769735368617270426C6F672E4E6574546F706F6C6F677953756974652E47656F6D6574726965732E47656F6D65747279466163746F7279030000000E707265636973696F6E4D6F64656C19636F6F7264696E61746553657175656E6365466163746F72790473726964040400374769735368617270426C6F672E4E6574546F706F6C6F677953756974652E47656F6D6574726965732E507265636973696F6E4D6F64656C02000000474769735368617270426C6F672E4E6574546F706F6C6F677953756974652E47656F6D6574726965732E436F6F7264696E617465417272617953657175656E6365466163746F72790200000008020000000909000000090A000000000000000708000000000100000001000000041D47656F4150492E47656F6D6574726965732E49436F6F7264696E61746503000000090B0000000509000000374769735368617270426C6F672E4E6574546F706F6C6F677953756974652E47656F6D6574726965732E507265636973696F6E4D6F64656C02000000096D6F64656C54797065057363616C6504002147656F4150492E47656F6D6574726965732E507265636973696F6E4D6F64656C7303000000060200000005F4FFFFFF2147656F4150492E47656F6D6574726965732E507265636973696F6E4D6F64656C73010000000776616C75655F5F000803000000000000000000000000000000050A000000474769735368617270426C6F672E4E6574546F706F6C6F677953756974652E47656F6D6574726965732E436F6F7264696E617465417272617953657175656E6365466163746F72790000000002000000050B000000334769735368617270426C6F672E4E6574546F706F6C6F677953756974652E47656F6D6574726965732E436F6F7264696E6174650300000001780179017A000000060606020000000BEE77280AB404C0AD4D637B2DBA4940000000000000F8FF0B
```

As can be seen, the value determined from what has been passed to `SetParameter()` and passed in the command is different.

Is it possible to pass a type to a named query to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out after inspecting the `NHibernate.Type.IType` concrete types that the `SetParameter()` takes as a third argument. The following works

```
private static SqlGeography GetPoint(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    var geographyBuilder = new SqlGeographyBuilder();
    geographyBuilder.SetSrid(4326);
    geographyBuilder.BeginGeography(OpenGisGeographyType.Point);
    geographyBuilder.BeginFigure(latitude, longitude);
    geographyBuilder.EndFigure();
    geographyBuilder.EndGeography();
    return geographyBuilder.ConstructedGeography;
}

var query = Session.GetNamedQuery("my-sproc-name");

var point = GetPoint(latitude, longitude);
query.SetParameter(
    "Location", 
    point, 
    new NHibernate.Spatial.Type.SqlGeographyType());

// my-sproc-name is mapped to return a collection of EntityA types
query.List<EntityA>();
```

the `NHibernate.Spatial.Type.SqlGeographyType` type can be found in the **[NHibernate.Spatial.dll](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/files/NHibernate.Spatial/2.1.2.GA/)** assembly.